# Create user in oracle database

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-grant

I have below requirement in oracle database

1. Create User and grant to all objects in schema "abc"
2. If i add any tables to schema "abc", then the user should have access by default without executing individual Grant

Current we are executing Grant statements for every objects created in schema, is there any onetime configuration available? Please help

Note: Here user is not a schema owner, for ex. some one who having access to read-only access.

Comment: not exactly possible as stated.  Use ROLES - and grant privs to them for new objects - users in the ROLE will then get the priv.

Comment: for every new object we need to grant access to roles?

Comment: yes - if you want to grant privs on those objects to others..

Answer (score 1):

In current versions of Oracle, you could create a DDL Trigger and have this automatically execute a grant on the newly created object to your other user.

See the excellent PSOUG site for an overview: http://psoug.org/reference/ddl_trigger.html

Comment: Thanks. we have a problem here, i have access to create objects but not having access to Grant, so another team has to run the Grant scripts. we need solution to avoid executing grant script every time new object created, something like configuring user while creating schema itself.